# php update query error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update my account information but getting the same error all the time

```
public function update_user() {
$obj_db = $this->obj_db();
 $query_update = "update `users` set "
            . "first_name='$_POST[first_name]',"
            . "middle_name='$_POST[middle_name]',"
            . "last_name='$_POST[last_name]',"
            . "email='$_POST[email]',"
            . "gender='$_POST[gender]',"
            . "contact_number='$_POST[contact_number]'"
            . "where `userID` = '$this->userID'";


    $r4 = $obj_db->query($query_update);

    if ($obj_db->affected_rows == 0) {
        throw new Exception(" * Update user information error <br> Nothing Update");
    }
}
```

[form will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbkI4.jpg)

[Am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu0VC.jpg)

Comment: show us the `<form ...>...</form>` code as well.

Comment: sir i had edited the post

Comment: can you take a picture of how the screen looks when the error happens?

Comment: just a sec sir i am uploading

Comment: I mean a picture of the website, not a picture of the code

Comment: Sir i have attached the picture with the post

Comment: Is there any output if you include `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: no sir their is no error including mysqli_error()

Comment: You most likely have an SQL injection vulnerability wide enough for anything to fit through. Do some input validation, and most importantly use prepared statements instead of mixing code with data [or at least escape the data from being interpreted as code]

Comment: To debug this: print out the sql query that's generated ... will tell you a lot more than the thrown exception.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

If appears that `$this->userID` is empty (per you're `echo`'ing of `$query_update` from the comments). Seeing as how my *answer* does still stand as your query would have failed even *with* `$this->userID` containing a value, I've decided to leave it here with this edit in place.

**ORIGINAL**

If you had error_reporting *on*, you'd be receiving a "*Notice: Use of undefined constant*", or something to that effect, as your `$_POST` array keys need to be wrapped in quotes, like so:

```
$_POST['contact_number']
```

Instead of:

```
$_POST[contact_number]
```

Your `$query_update` variable would then become:

```
$query_update = "update `users` set "
                    . "first_name='$_POST['first_name']',"
                    . "middle_name='$_POST['middle_name']',"
                    . "last_name='$_POST['last_name']',"
                    . "email='$_POST['email']',"
                    . "gender='$_POST['gender']',"
                    . "contact_number='$_POST['contact_number']'"
                    . "where `userID` = '$this->userID'";
```

Because your array keys were not wrapped in quotes they were assumed (by the PHP parser) to be constants. Since they are not constants, defined within your application, they are not valid array keys. However, this would only throw a *notice* which was why your script continued to execute.

You can read more about [PHP constants here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php).

Comment: Doesn't  work 

$query_update = "update `users` set "
                . "first_name='".$_POST['first_name']."',"
                . "middle_name='".$_POST['middle_name']."',"
                . "last_name='".$_POST['last_name']."',"
                . "email='".$_POST['email']."',"
                . "gender='".$_POST['gender']."',"
                . "contact_number='".$_POST['contact_number']."'"
                . "where `userID` = '$this->userID'";

Comment: Add this to your script and rerun: `echo $query_update;` Are you getting expected values for your query?

Comment: get this output 

update `users` set first_name='Husnain',middle_name='Ali',last_name='Khan',email='husnainali5@gmail.com',gender='Male',contact_number='03346767666'where `userID` = ''

Comment: So `$this->userID` is empty. You need to fix that.

Comment: Is there a record in the `users` table with whatever `$this->userID` is now holding? If you run `echo $query_update;`, grab the output, and paste it into phpMyAdmin or wherever, do you get the expected results? There's a lot of things you could trying here.